# Dos CMOS update without a VGA monitor

Tags: bios

We have been shipping product to the fields for 25+ years. The product has a DOS based computer - embedded with no monitor. We have had cases of corrupt CMOS expired batteries etc. We typically have the boards sent back to our factory where we install them in a system that has a monitor and reset the CMOS.

Is there a way to do this without a monitor. Possibly using console or floppy.

We have a known good CMOS config.

Comment: Step 1: Find a floppy drive.  :-)  Are you talking about a mechanism to use at your own facility, or something you could have users do, themselves, in the field?

Comment: If you sell enough of them you can have your own firmware (BIOS) made for you with desired defaults. Which should help with future problems. Until then please add the information requesed by @fixer. Alsom if all firmware acts the same you could write a manual on how to set it (e.g press DEL, wait 10 seconds, press cursur left, cursure right 4 times, press enter, cursor down, enter, ESC, ... Prone to failure and surely a kludge, but it should work).